# Why Cant I install Ruby 2.2.10 on a clean install Mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I built an app a while back on my macbook using Ruby 2.2.1 and can't seem to get the environment to run the app or even install the Ruby on my replaced Macbook. I did a clean install on my desktop Mac and I am getting the same issue. Is there a way to get this Ruby installed? Using Rbenv to install on homebrew.

```
BUILD FAILED (macOS 12.5 using ruby-build 20220726)
Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/c_...
    Results logged to /var/folders/c_/vydvf3y11v10dzyyp87nqrw40000gn/T/ruby-build.20220808163357.8947.log

Last 10 log lines:
    rb_ivar_set(enumerator, rb_intern("slicewhen_pred"), pred);
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/ruby/ruby.h:1475:51: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
```

The full build log is [here](https://gist.github.com/SupremeA/0ff158db831330623e94a36d12eae83e)

Comment: Please post the full build log. The real reason will be in the log. You have to read it to know what went wrong. If the log is huge you can put it up as a github gist, or any other text paste website so that SO users can take a look.

Comment: Please, do *NOT* post your information on third-party websites. All the information required to answer your question must be *in your question*. Not in comments, not on third-party websites. In the question. If the information is too big to put into the question, then you need to narrow down the problem, not just dump the information somewhere else.

Comment: Here is the full build log https://gist.github.com/SupremeA/0ff158db831330623e94a36d12eae83e

Answer (score 2):

This ruby version **is no longer supported**, so it is highly not recommended to use it for your projects. You may find a bug that will never be fixed, refer to the information below.

eol (end-of-life): Branch is not supported by the ruby-core team any longer and does not receive any fixes. No further patch release will be released.

```
Ruby 2.2  
status: eol  
release date: 2014-12-25  
EOL date: 2018-03-31
```

https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/branches/

Comment: I am aware of the EOL but I need to access it so that I can begin upgrading it.

Comment: I'll bet you're stuck for now, at least on a modern version of macOS. What I've had to do is use [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com) (historically) or [Docker](https://www.docker.com) (recently) to run a virtualized instance of the application instead. You can build that off of older Ubuntu bases, for example. Ruby on macOS was impacted pretty severely when Apple moved away from OpenSSL. Modern versions of Ruby have been adapted, older ones have not.

Comment: This needs to be removed, as it only breaks Google results when searching for an actual solution to the problem.